# Cannot cast pointer field while can cast same pointer defined within method in managed classes

Tags: c++-cli

I have unmanaged object of WtfClass.

```
class WtfClass    {    };
```

And I also have managed class which uses pointer to this object.

```
ref class MyClass  //works fine if you remove "ref"
{
public:
    void MyMethod();
    void WtfMethod(void * pVoid);
    WtfClass *pWtfStruct;
};

void MyClass::MyMethod()
{
    /*WtfClass* pWtfStruct;  //if you uncomment this it will compile even with ref*/
    WtfMethod((int*)(&pWtfStruct));  //(!!!invalid type conversion here)
}

void MyClass::WtfMethod(void *pVoid)
{}
```

I can't cast WtfClass* pointer from field, but can easily cast the same pointer defined within MyMethod(). If make MyClass unmanaged it works in any case.

It's better to look at screenshots:

1. https://ibin.co/2iOcN1ooaC7A.png **[using ref-bad.png]**
2. https://ibin.co/2iOcYtP84H0e.png **[using ref-good.png]**
3. ibin.co/2iOcjCCc2gQe.png **[without ref.png]** (sorry not enough reputation to paste more than 2 links)

Of course I can have workaround like this, but I'd like to understand why this happening:

```
void MyClass::MyMethod()
{
    WtfClass* pWorkAround = pWtfStruct;  //not required in this case
    WtfMethod((void*)(&pWorkAround));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so to summarize, without the duplicate field & local variable names:

```
ref class MyClass
{
    WtfClass* fieldWtfPtr;

    void foo()
    {
        WtfClass* localvarWtfPtr;

        WtfMethod((int*)(&fieldWtfPtr)); // Error
        WtfMethod((int*)(&localvarWtfPtr)); // Works
    }
};
```

Side question: `&fieldWtfPtr` is of type `WtfClass**`, a double pointer. Did you mean to cast that to a `int**`, also a double pointer? Or perhaps did you want to take `fieldWtfPtr` as a `WtfClass*` single pointer and cast that to a `int*` single pointer?

Here's why you're getting the error: `MyClass` is a managed object. The garbage compiler is allowed to move it around at any point, without telling you. So, it's location in memory can change at any point. So when you try to take the address of a class field, it's not valid because the address of that field can change at any point!

Why the other things make it work:

- Local variables are stored on the stack, and the stack doesn't get moved around by the garbage collector, so it is valid to take the address of a local variable.
- If you remove the `ref`, then `MyClass` is no longer a managed object, so the garbage collector won't move it around, so now the addresses of its fields won't change willy-nilly.

For this case, the easiest fix would be to make use of a local temporary variable.

```
void foo()
{
    WtfClass* localCopyWtfPtr = this->fieldWtfPtr;

    WtfMethod((int*)(&localCopyWtfPtr)); // Works

    // If WtfMethod changed the data, write it back.
    this->fieldWtfPtr = localCopyWtfPtr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When I tried to recreate this, the compiler generated the following error:

> error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from 'cli::interior_ptr<CWtfClass*>' to 'LPVOID *'

I think what is going on here is some magic that allows managed classes to have unmanaged members. The [MSDN documentation for cli::interior_ptr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0fh545k.aspx) describes what's going on - basically this is used to allow for the managed object to change its memory address in the managed heap, which would cause problems when native pointers come in to play.

The reason that assigning the member to a variable first works is most likely because it has an implicit conversion to the template parameter, but since it is a managed type the compiler won't allow you to get the address of the variable (since the garbage collector can move it around in memory as needed).

The workaround in your question is probably the best way to fix this compiler error.

Answer (score 1):

David answered *why* this happens and suggested a workaround for your case.

I'll just post a different solution here: You can *pin* your managed object to tell the GC not to move it around. The most lightweight way to do that is through `pin_ptr` (the GC won't even know you pinned something unless it stumbles upon your code in the middle of a collection). As long as it stays in scope, the managed object will be *pinned* and won't move. It's best if you avoid pinning for too long, but this lets you get a pointer to a chunk of managed memory which is guaranteed not to move - it's helpful when you want to avoid copying things around.

Here's how to do it:

```
pin_ptr<WtfClass*> pin(&pWtfStruct);
WtfMethod(pin);
```

`pin` acts just like a `WtfClass**`.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding side question of **David Yaw**.
I faced with this problem while used some WINAPI functions.

```
IAudioEndpointVolume* pWtfVolume = NULL;    
pDevice->Activate(__uuidof(IAudioEndpointVolume), CLSCTX_ALL, NULL, (void**)&pWtfVolume);
pWtfVolume->SetMute(BST_CHECKED, pGuidMyContext);
```

And it's working only if I pass &pWtfVolume. Ironically you can pass argument without "&", just pFieldVolume and compiler will say OKAY, but interface IAudioEndpointVolume will not work.

Look at this:

```
ref class MyClass
{
    WtfClass* fieldWtfPtr;

    void foo()
    {
        WtfClass* localvarWtfPtr;

        WtfMethod((int*)(&fieldWtfPtr)); // Error
        WtfMethod((int*)(&localvarWtfPtr)); // Works
        WtfMethod((int*)(fieldWtfPtr)); // Compiles!!!
    }
};
```

Comment: This is because of the `void*` type - it's not type safe, you can pass it an `int*`, or `int**` or even `int*******` if you'd like, it will still implicitly convert to `void*`.